# How to get a random entry from Castle ActiveRecord in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, activerecord, castle-windsor

There are probably many ways to do it, which one is the quickest and most efficient?

Answer (score 0):

In Nhibernate you can select a random row like so

```
var query = "SELECT top 1 * from [Event] ORDER BY NEWID()";
ISQLQuery qry = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).AddEntity(typeof(Event));
Event randomevent = qry.List<Event>().First();
```

In active record we have to work a little harder and use the following.

```
 Event randomEvent = (Event)ActiveRecordMediator<Event>.Execute(
    (session, instance) =>
        {

            var query = "SELECT top 1 * from [Event] ORDER BY NEWID()";

            ISQLQuery qry = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).AddEntity(typeof(Event));
            Event rand = qry.List<Event>().First();

            return rand;
        },new Event());
```

Just replace `event` with your entity.